# CSS: Vertical sidebar button

Tags: css

Anyone have code for sidebar button (fixed + 90deg)? Can't seem to find anything solid.

see demo / idea

https://codepen.io/clientagency/pen/MWgmKMx

```
see the pen
```

Comment: Hate the idea of using png for the button which would fix the issue but not a very clean solution

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this example I created:

```css
.sticky-container {
  background-color: #06c;
  box-shadow: gray -1px 1px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 3px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 right: 0px;
 width: 60px;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 9999;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
 margin-top: -24px;
 text-align: center;
  color: white;
  }
 a {
  padding:0 !important;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  color: #ffff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<button class="sticky-container">
  <div class="button-container">
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</button>

<!-- Test Date -->

<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a professional fixed sidebar and a stylish button with readable vertical text, check out this JSFiddle I made for you: https://jsfiddle.net/4y5Lhp3c/1/. The button only goes from horizontal to vertical when the page is done loading, so be patient :)

Markup:

```
<input type="button" value="Contact Us" id="vert" />
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vert').val('c\no\nn\nt\na\nc\nt\n\nu\ns');   
});
```